# How can I keep midnight (00:00h) using strptime() in R?

Tags: r, date, datetime, format, posixct

I have a dataframe, df, which has factor variable for date in the following format:

```
2015-12-15 10:00:00
2015-12-19 12:00:00
2015-12-20 20:00:00
```

It is hourly data. The problem arises when looking at midnight, 00:00:00, because it doesn't appear the hour. It just says:

```
21/12/2015
```

So as you see, it only says the day but it lacks the hour.
So I use strptime to convert to a date format using:

```
df$date <- strptime(df$date,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

It all works fine for all the hours and days except for any day at midnight, 00:00:00, which returns:

```
NA
```

I'd really appreciate some help as I've been looking at previous posts in StackOverflow and other forums but I havent' managed to figure out the solution for this specific problem yet.

Comment: Those can't be the format of your date variables in your data.frame. If so, the format string `"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"` shouldn't work for any of them. that says "day/month/year hour:min", not "year-month-day hour:min:sec" Be sure to actually provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I think the problem is just the string representation of POSIXct dates... when you print a POSIXct object, by default it hides the time portion when it's 00:00:00, but the information is still there... just try to print it with `format(dates,"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From R's [strptime](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) documentation (emphasis added):

> format
>
> A character string. The default for the format methods is "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" **if any element has a time component which is not midnight, and "%Y-%m-%d" otherwise**. If options("digits.secs") is set, up to the specified number of digits will be printed for seconds.

So the information is still there, you just need to `format` it to print it out with the time components.

```
> midnight <- strptime("2015-12-19 00:00:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
> midnight
[1] "2015-12-19 EST"
> format(midnight,"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
[1] "2015/12/19 00:00"
```

Answer (score 3):

If we have a `vector` like "v1", by using `strptime` we get NA for those elements that don't have the correct format

```
strptime(v1,  "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
#[1] "2015-12-19 12:00:00 UTC" NA
```

One way to correct this will be to `paste` the "00:00:00" string for those that doesn't have that

```
v1[!grepl(":", v1)] <- paste(v1[!grepl(":", v1)], "00:00:00") 
strptime(v1,  "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
#[1] "2015-12-19 12:00:00 UTC" "2015-12-19 00:00:00 UTC"
```

---

Or if we use `lubridate`, the `parse_date_time` can take multiple formats

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(v1, guess_formats(v1, c("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", "%d/%m/%Y")))
#[1] "2015-12-19 12:00:00 UTC" "2015-12-19 00:00:00 UTC"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("19/12/2015 12:00:00", "19/12/2015")
```