# posix time at 12AM

Tags: r

Why does as.POSIXct fail to parse 12:00 for me as 00:00:00?

```
> as.POSIXct('11:59 PM',format='%I:%M %p')
 [1] "2021-10-31 23:59:00 EDT"
> as.POSIXct('12:00 AM',format='%I:%M %p')
 [1] "2021-10-31 EDT"
> as.POSIXct('12:01 AM',format='%I:%M %p')
 [1] "2021-10-31 00:01:00 EDT"
```

Comment: Related: [How can I keep midnight (00:00h) using strptime() in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089536/how-can-i-keep-midnight-0000h-using-strptime-in-r)

Comment: `as.POSIXct` doesn't _fail_ to parse midnight, it just doesn't print it. `print.POSIXct` calls `format.POSIXct`, which omits midnight.

Comment: @Henrik OK great. I only need the times to do arithmetic on.

Answer (score 1):

It is related to the `format` i.e. if we check the `?as.POSIXct`

> format - character string giving a date-time format as used by strptime.

Therefore, check the `?strptime`

> format - A character string. The default for the format methods is "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" **if any element has a time component which is not midnight, and "%Y-%m-%d" otherwise**. If options("digits.secs") is set, up to the specified number of digits will be printed for seconds.

Comment: Additional note: We could use `library(lubridate)
hm('12:00 AM')` .

Comment: I think the answer could be improved using Henrik's comment, that not only is the behavior related to "format" but it is only related to "format" and not "as.POSIXct", which stores the correct midnight representation. Maybe it's what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `lubridate` package:

```
library(lubridate) 
hm('12:00 AM')
```